# Strategy to display value for a HTML select

Tags: java, jquery, spring, internationalization

Strategy to display value for a html select

I have a spring boot, application. On the client side, I use JQuery

I would like to know the strategy to display "static value" for a html select.

Example

In the table communicationType I have:

```
1 - mobile
2 - fix
3 - email
```

Actually, I put directly the data in the html select.

Not nice for internationalization. Maybe it's not good to put this in a database.

Maybe it's better to don't have a table for this kind of data?
Is it better to create an enum, put enum value in a properties file? Put value in db but use a kind of key for the string and put this key in a properties file?

Comment: It's hard to tell - is your question "How do I do internationalization with Java spring boot"?

Comment: Basically, this question is **How do I internationalize a List of Values when they are stored in the database?** Frankly, I have the same question. I'm dealing with an application right now with lots of List of Values (dropdown lists) populated by data from a database, where the display text is stored in the DB.

Answer (score 1):

Your question deals with several topics:

I) As you already noticed: *hard coding* something in HTML is very unflexible.
You should avoid that.

II) The values of your `select` represent a *list* of *data*. The place to keep your data is *typically* some knd of database. The format you store it in is the *canonical* form for your application (whatever language you use internally).

III) Outside of your application, you use an *internationalized* representation of your *canonical* form. That involves somewhere a *translation*-step in your *rendering pipeline*.

[Tutorial for Spring Boot](https://justinrodenbostel.com/2014/05/13/part-4-internationalization-in-spring-boot/)

Where you store the translated strings is up to you and your application;
the common way is `properties`.

Answer (score 0):

You could specify localization by passing an argument to a backend API that returns a list of text values. You could also perform localization client-side. The storage medium isn't going to help you here in the sense that you must map to a single representation regardless so storing it in a relational structure could involve a fair amount of complexity. A 'properties' file is probably not the best place for this.
Once you have the localized data, you can insert it via JavaScript (for example with the jQuery library).

Comment: could be maybe a better idea to have an enum for this kind of data and use enum value in a properties file to get i18n value.